# How can I get the addresses of all the EC2 instances tied to a LoadBalancer using Boto?

Tags: boto

I'd like to get all the instances that are on a LoadBalancer with boto, how can I accomplish that?

This is what I've got so far:

```
import boto
from boto.regioninfo import RegionInfo
from boto import ec2

ACCESS_KEY_ID = '*****'
SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '********'

reg = RegionInfo(
    name='ap-southeast-1', 
    endpoint='elasticloadbalancing.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com')

conn = boto.connect_elb(
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, 
    region=reg)

ec2_connection = boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection(
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, 
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region=reg)

instances = [ instance.id for instance in conn.get_all_load_balancers()[3].instances ] 
# instances is now [u'i-62448d36'], so far so good.
ec2_connection.get_all_instances(instances)
```

Which ends with:

> ```
> <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSFault/2005-15-09">
>   <Error>
>     <Type>Sender</Type>
>     <Code>InvalidAction</Code>
>     <Message>Could not find operation DescribeInstances for version 2012-03-01</Message>
>   </Error>
>   <RequestId>c6aab70d-b22b-11e1-a990-a747bbde9f63</RequestId>
> </ErrorResponse>
> ```

I'm using boto 2.4.1.

Comment: That's because the RegionInfo object you have created has the elasticloadbalancing endpoint in it rather than the ec2 endpoint.  You have to create another RegionInfo for EC2 or you can use "import boto.ec2; ec2_connection=boto.ec2.connect_to_region('ap-southest-1')" to get the EC2Connection object.

Comment: @garnaat Ah yeah, I noticed that after a while. It was a bit counterintuitive that I couldn't use the same object for the region.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what I ended up with:

```
import boto
from boto import regioninfo
from boto import ec2

ACCESS_KEY_ID = '***********'
SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '***********'

elb_region = boto.regioninfo.RegionInfo(
    name='ap-southeast-1', 
    endpoint='elasticloadbalancing.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com')

elb_connection = boto.connect_elb(
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, 
    region=elb_region)

ec2_region = ec2.get_region(
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, 
    region_name='ap-southeast-1')

ec2_connection = boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection(
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region=ec2_region)

load_balancer = elb_connection.get_all_load_balancers(load_balancer_names=['MediaPopClients'])[0]
instance_ids = [ instance.id for instance in load_balancer.instances ]
reservations = ec2_connection.get_all_instances(instance_ids)
instance_addresses = [ i.public_dns_name for r in reservations for i in r.instances ]
```

Gives:

> [u'ec2-46-137-194-58.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com']

Comment: I am getting InvalidCertificateException when using above script, Looks like something wrong with ssl certificates.

Comment: @ManjitKumar it's not related to script. Your computers certs might be out of date, could be a firewall thing, could be boto needs to update, could be a temporary aws hiccup.

Answer (score 4):

I think something like this should work:

```
>>> import boto
>>> elb = boto.connect_elb()
>>> load_balancer = elb.get_all_load_balancers(['my_lb_name'])[0]
>>> for instance_info in load_balancer.instances:
...    print instance_info.id
```

The instances attribute of the LoadBalancer object is a list of InstanceInfo objects.  These are not actual Instance object but it does have the instance-id so you can then look up the Instance object associated with it.

Comment: Thanks, that's about as far as I got yesterday. It seems like AWS is complaining when I try to get details on the instance id's though, have you managed to retrieve the details yourself?